# python, write mixed value to class/instance

Tags: python, class, object, variables, instance

i have a class which is called "devices" incl. two attributes e.g "device_name" and "serial_number". unfortunately i need to create instance names like "10M2-12AAA3BC42" (mixed values, string & numbers) The lengths of the names differs.

I can create the instance "10M2-12AAA3BC42". But if i call "10M2-12AAA3BC42"

```
print(10M2-12AAA3BC42.serial_number)
```

i'm getting an "invalid syntax".

Is there a way to use mixed values as described above?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not define variable with starting with integers

Comment: No, if you want to do it this way (check out [`str.isidentifier`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.isidentifier#str.isidentifier) as a helpful tool to identify vaild identifiers). You coud manage your sturctures through a dictionary and use the strings as keys instead?

Comment: Thanks @Timus , still I am surprised , how did @Mr. Miyagi manage to create instance with name `10M2-12AAA3BC42`

Comment: @JohnByro I don't think they were ... :)

Comment: I have answered about the naming but Share the code or write dummy code which reflects your codes then I would help you with creating instance you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your naming identifiers is not correct. You might try below to access attributes

```
    class devices:
        def __init__(self, device_name , s_no):
            self.device_name = device_name
            self.s_no = s_no

    _10M2_12AAA3BC42 = devices('10M2', '12AAA3BC42')

    print(_10M2_12AAA3BC42.s_no)
    print(_10M2_12AAA3BC42.device_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples of naming the identifiers in python

```py
num1
FLAG
get_user_name
userDetails
_1234
```

In your case, It should be something like this: `_10M2_12AAA3BC42`. (you can't use hyphen- anywhere in the name and name should not begin with number)